# how to do the type reduction of the Liskov's trans function in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm a beginner for scalaz. Here is the source code:

```
sealed abstract class Liskov[-A, +B] {         
  def apply(a: A): B = Liskov.witness(this)(a)
  def subst[F[-_]](p: F[B]): F[A]     
  final def *[+[+_, +_], C, D](that: Liskov[C, D]): Liskov[A + C, B + D] = Liskov.lift2(this, that)
  final def andThen[C](that: Liskov[B, C]): Liskov[A, C] = Liskov.trans(that, this)
  final def compose[C](that: Liskov[C, A]): Liskov[C, B] = Liskov.trans(this, that)
  def onF[X](fa: X => A): X => B = Liskov.co2_2[Function1, B, X, A](this)(fa)
}

object Liskov extends LiskovInstances {
  def trans[A, B, C](f: B <~< C, g: A <~< B): A <~< C =
    g.subst[λ[`-α` => α <~< C]](f)  
}
```

I don't know how to do the type reduction for the function `trans`.

Comment: It's been a while since you asked your question. Anyway if the question remains could you be more specific what is your problem? What do you mean by "doing type reduction"?

Answer (score 0):

First, determine what `A` and `B` for the purposes of the `subst` method by examining `g`'s type; as it happens, in this context `A=A` and `B=B`, but if you want to be really clear you should probably rename those type parameters of `trans`.

Now take your type function:

```
`-α` => α <~< C
```

`subst` applies the argument `F` to `B` in the value argument and `A` in the result. So for the argument, ask "what happens when I call this typelambda with `B`?" For the result type, ask "what happens when I call this typelambda with `A`?"